# WebView user agent

Tags: android, android-webview

I have WebView which loads one mobile site, I need send to user agent to the server how it to realize?

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
mWebView.loadUrl("http://searchmp3.mobi/");   
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Checkout the [`setUserAgentString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString%28java.lang.String%29) method in the [WebSettings](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html), e.g.

```
mWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("My user agent string, here");
```

Comment: How can I get the basic data to be sent?

Answer (score -3):

try this one

```
 WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);    
 WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();    
 webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);  
 wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```