# Making WebView http request so that website/service does NOT return mobile specific content

Tags: android

I am creating a Webview that loads content from a  site that provides mobile specific http response. The problem is I don't want this response, I would prefer the regular feed.  How can I keep the website from treating the request as from a mobile device? I am thinking maybe there is a way to keep the website from recognizing the request as from mobile.  Perhaps a manifest option or some option in the Webview?

Comment: You could change the [user agent][1] in the Webview.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11273132/1916258

Answer (score 0):

```
String UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1";

WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setUserAgentString(UserAgent);
```

or:

`myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(UserAgent);`