# Parse html with script execution

Tags: android, flash, html-parsing

Ok, so my problem goes like this: there is a page that loads Flash Player object with a script client-side, so html isn't created till after script is run on user's browser. I want to read `flashvars` attribute of said object.
What is the easiest way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a hidden WebView to load the website and get the resulting HTML as described here: [How do I get the web page contents from a WebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-webview/4892013#4892013)

For parsing HTML and looking for data in it there is http://jsoup.org/ or you can just run extra JavaScript inside the browser.

Comment: Btw, is there a way to ensure that the page will be loaded like for a pc browser with flash player installed, and not special version for mobile devices?

Comment: Tha a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273045/webview-user-agent . Not sure about flash player.